# How are ends chosen to start a new set following a tie-break?

Tags: rules, tennis

After a tie-break, how is it decided which end to start serving from in the following set?

Do players get a choice or do they keep the current end for one game or swap immediately?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [rules](http://officialtennisrules.com/changing-ends-of-the-court/) you change ends on every odd game.

So at the end of a Tie-break, they need to swap ends since the score will be 7-6. It does not matter where they started the game, just at the end of the game. It may seem strange since players swap after every 6 points in a tie break.

Also who ever started serving the tie-break will then receive the first game of the next set

I asked this to a national referee of my country (we played at the same tennis club) and he said you just need to swap ends at the end of the game. So whatever side you were on at the end of the game, swap ends

Answer (score 1):

Answer #1 is wrong. The tiebreaker counts as a service game for the player/doubles team that served first in the tiebreaker. It also counts as an odd numbered game (7-6 = 13) requiring a switch of ends upon its completion. At the conclusion of the tiebreaker, regardless what end the first serving team finishes the tiebreaker on, they go to the end opposite of where they began serving the tiebreaker and receive service there. Again, the tiebreaker is counted as a service game for the player who began serving the first point of the tiebreaker.

Comment: Can you cite a rule about that?  https://www.usta.com/en/home/improve/tips-and-instruction/national/tennis-scoring-rules.html does not seem to agree with that method of changing.